# How can I unit test a sub that's not exported by a module in Raku?

Tags: raku

Got this code:

```
unit module Command::CanRun;

enum OS <win nix>;

sub determine-os {
    return 'nix' when $*SPEC.gist.contains('unix', :i);
    return 'win' when $*DISTRO.is-win;
}
```

I would like to unit test this:

`ok Command::CanRun::determine-os, 'can determine os';`

However, I can't do this without exporting the `determine-os` sub:

`Could not find symbol '&determine-os' in 'Command::CanRun'`

Haven't been able to find any guidance on how to do this for non-exported subs in a module. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `sub` defaults to lexical scope, meaning that it cannot be accessed from the outside. One can make it available by the fully-qualified package name by making it `our` scoped:

```
our sub determine-os {
    return 'nix' when $*SPEC.gist.contains('unix', :i);
    return 'win' when $*DISTRO.is-win;
}
```

An alternative solution would be to export it under a tag (for example, `is export(:internals)`), which means that one would have to explicitly import it (`use Command::CanRun :internals;`), keeping it out of the standard API exported by the module.

Comment: Interesting approach. I like it. I assumed the only way would be to introspect the module somehow but this seems more straightforward.

Comment: No, lexical scoping in Raku is really strictly enforced (and thus can be depended upon by analyses, optimization, etc.)